# How do I write a nose2 plugin that separates different types of tests?

Tags: python, testing, nose2

I'm writing a plugin that will separate treat my unit tests, functional tests & integration tests differently.
My tests folder will have the following structure exactly:

> /tests
>    -- /unit
>    -- /functional
>    -- /integration

Each unit test will reside in the unit directory and each functional test will reside in the functional directory and so on.

I am familiar with the [Layers](http://nose2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/layers.html) plugin but I'd rather have my tests follow a convention.
Which hook exactly should I use to inject the appropriate Layer before tests are run?
Should it be the [loadTestsFromModule](http://nose2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dev/hook_reference.html#loadTestsFromModule) hook? Can you show me an example?

I'd also like to separate the summary report for each type of test.
Which hook should I use?

Comment: @Charles Oops I meant unittest2, not testsuite2. Your tagging is correct though :)

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to your problem? I am using nose2 as well and I have seen the [`attrib` plugin](https://nose2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html) but there is no decorator in nose2, just in nose1. And all the answers below are for nose1 as well.

Comment: I got this working with nose2 using the attrib plugin and some code copied from nose1. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35437984/346561) for details.

Answer (score 3):

I got this working with nose2 by using the nose2 `attrib` plugin for discovery and some code copied from the nose1 `attrib` plugin which allowed me to decorate my tests.

#### Using the nose2 `attrib` plugin

You will see [the nose2 `attrib` plugin](https://nose2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html) allows for custom attributes to be defined on test functions and classes.

For this to work, you have to specify the attributes of the tests after defining the test function.

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_function(self):
        self.assertEqual(1+1, 2)
    test_function.custom_attr1 = True
    test_function.custom_attr2 = ['foo', 'bar']
```

Then you can run a set of filtered tests by specifying `-A` or `--attribute` as a `nose2` command-line argument to list the attribute(s) you to match against your test suite. You can even use the [expression command-line argument](https://nose2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html#select-tests-using-python-expressions) of `-E` or `--eval-attribute` which allows more complex Python expressions for matching test attributes.

e.g. `nose2 -v -A custom_attr1`
will run all tests which have a `custom_attr1` specified with a **truthy** value.

#### Using decorators to specify test attributes

This wasn't quite good enough for me though because I didn't like the idea of defining these attributes on tests after their definition. I wanted to use a decorator instead but `nose2` didn't have a built-in decorator for doing this.

I went to the [nose1 source code for its `attrib` plugin](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html#source) and copied the source for the `attr` function.

```
def attr(*args, **kwargs):
    """Decorator that adds attributes to classes or functions
    for use with the Attribute (-a) plugin.
    """
    def wrap_ob(ob):
        for name in args:
            setattr(ob, name, True)
        for name, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(ob, name, value)
        return ob
    return wrap_ob
```

I put this into a `test/attrib_util.py` file. Now I can specify attributes using the decorator instead. My original test class code from above can be converted to the (IMO) simpler:

```
from test.attrib_util import attr

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @attr('custom_attr1', custom_attr2=['foo', 'bar'])
    def test_function(self):
        self.assertEqual(1+1, 2)
```

You will notice that the attributes can be specified as either args or kwargs; all args will get a default value of `True`.

You can also even use this `attr` decorator on a test class or base class and the attributes will be applied to all test functions defined within. This allows for very easy separation of unit and functional tests.

```
from test.attrib_util import attr

@attr('functional')
class FunctionalTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    pass

class MyFunctionalCase(FunctionalTestCase):
    def test_function(self):
        print 'this will be considered a "functional" test function'
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write a plug-in, [the built-in attr module](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html) is designed for this purpose. It does not depend on your file hierarchy, however.  Instead, you mark individual tests as unit, functional, or integration.  This would look like:

```py
from nose.plugins import attrib

@attrib.attr("functional")
class FunctionalTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    pass
```

To run only the functional tests, you would then do:

```
nosetests -a functional
```

If I were creating this test layout, I would probably have 3 unittest.TestCase subclasses, already marked with "unit", "functional", and "integration".  New tests could easily inherit the proper test type.

Comment: This answer is for Nose1, not Nose2.  (They're very similar, but not quite the same)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the tests sorted into directories (as you mentioned), you could write a plugin that uses the [wantDirectory](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/interface.html#nose.plugins.base.IPluginInterface.wantDirectory) method.

```
import os.path
from nose.plugins import Plugin

class TestCategory(Plugin):
    """
    Run tests in a defined category (unittest, functional, integration.  Always
    runs uncategorized tests.
    """
    def wantDirectory(self, dirname):
         dirname = os.path.basename(dirname)
         if (dirname in ('unit', 'functional', 'integration') and 
             dirname != self.category):
             return False
         return None
```

You will want to write `options()` and `configure()` methods for this plug-in to deal with enabling and disabling it and gleaning the user's choice of category.  When running nosetests you would choose from the three categories:

```
nosetests --category functional
```

Since only one test category is run at a time, you would get a separate report for each test category.  You could always, of course, run all tests by not enabling this plugin.

(adding as a different answer because it is a completely different approach).

Comment: See the tags. They refer to nose2.

Comment: whoops. sorry. I'll delete these answers.